# Angular 9 Template re subscribes to Observable on mouse click when using getter function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just spent a long time debugging an issue I do not understand.
Basically every time I clicked on a button or anything with a click event on my page the template of a particular component would re-subscribe to an observable, even when clicking on un-related components on the page.

NB: All my components also use OnPush Change Detection.

In my Angular 9 component I had the following piece of code.

Notice that this is a `getter` function!

```
public get riskFactorModel(): Observable<ModelBuilderModel> {
    return this.model('riskFactors').pipe(map(riskFactors => {
      // Do stuff here 
    }));
  }
```

And in my template I had this

```
<div *ngIf="(riskFactorModel | async) let _riskFactor">
        <div class="errors" *ngIf="_riskFactor.modelErrors && _riskFactor.modelErrors.length > 0">
          <div *ngFor="let error of _riskFactor.modelErrors">
            {{error.message}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

All I have done is move the observable to a property on my component like so

```
export class RiskFactorsBuilderComponent extends ComponentBase implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      
    public riskFactorModel: Observable<ModelBuilderModel>;
    
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    
      public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.riskFactorModel = this.getRiskFactorModel();
      }
    
      public getRiskFactorModel(): Observable<ModelBuilderModel> {
        return // do getObservable stuff here 
    }
}
```

And now the constant re-subscription to the observable has stopped?!?! Can someone please explain to me why, this feels like a bug with Angular to me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please make some prototype somewhere which i best way to represent your problem, so that other quickly get into probleum and give solution to you

Comment: @Jadli Please read my post. I have found the solution I just don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

every time a change detection cycle is run your getter was getting invoked and was providing a new observable you were subscribing too. putting the observable in a property is the only way around it (known to me).
P.S. why your change detection was running if you have OnPush strategy is another question. And `getter` is still a function that gets called, it's now the same as property

Comment: I understand that all getters and setters are also functions. So why if I convert it to a property does the issue disappear?

Comment: property value is an object, and angular can compare object reference from previous change detection cycle with the current one, and if they are the same, the corresponding html does not get rerendered. your getter function is providing a new instance of observable on every change detection run, hence the issue